# React Native exported application not communicating with the server

Tags: react-native

I created an application that communicates with my created fast-api backend. While I developped the application it was working fine, but after when everything was done, I exported the application.

After this I installed this application on multiple device, but after starting the application I can't login through the login panel. Or I cant even register. Its like there is no connection between the apk and the server.

I looked for some questions but I didn't see something similar. Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: post the code you're using to connect to your backend please, very hard to help without knowing anything about what's happening.  have you tried making the requests through postman?

Comment: Its not the backend, because everything works fine when I was developing, so when i installed the application with npm on my phone its works fine, but after exporting it and installing it manually, it just not communicating with the server i dont know why

Comment: Nobody can help without seeing your code